# Looping over column names and adding column names to dplyr summary tables in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I want to loop over many columns to get a dplyr summary of age for each factor level of each column. I also want to add the column name to the dplyr table I created but I am having issues assigning that as well

I have tried to do the following using assign:

```
for(var in c("Sex", "Smoke", "Diabetes", "HIV")) {
  assign(paste0("mean_",var))<-df%>%group_by(var) %>%
    summarise(meanAge=mean(Age), sdAge=sd(Age))
}
```

I basically want summary tables of age for each column (mean_Sex, mean_Smoke, mean_Diabetes, and mean_HIV)

But I am getting error:

Error in `group_by_prepare()`:
! Must group by variables found in `.data`.

- Column `var` is not found.
  Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Can anyone help with a way to do this?

data example:

```
structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), 
    Sex = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), Smoke = structure(c(3L, 
    1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("N", 
    "NA", "Y"), class = "factor"), Diabetes = structure(c(3L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("N", 
    "NA", "Y"), class = "factor"), HIV = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("N", 
    "NA", "Y"), class = "factor"), Age = c(23, 24, 43, 35, 18, 
    29, 25, 17, 22, 20, 55, 54)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(Sex:HIV) %>%
  group_by(name, value) %>%
  summarize(meanAge = mean(Age), sdAge = sd(Age)) %>%
  ungroup()


   name     value meanAge sdAge
   <chr>    <fct>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Diabetes N        21    3.61
 2 Diabetes NA       36.8 20.5 
 3 Diabetes Y        31    8.12
 4 HIV      N        28.6 14.3 
 5 HIV      NA       38.3 19.4 
 6 HIV      Y        26.8  7.14
 7 Sex      F        30.8 14.4 
 8 Sex      M        30.1 13.8 
 9 Smoke    N        35.5 16.4 
10 Smoke    NA       24    5.57
11 Smoke    Y        30.2 14.9
```

or for differently shaped output:

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(Sex:HIV) %>%
  group_by(name, value) %>%
  summarize(meanAge = mean(Age), sdAge = sd(Age), .groups = "drop") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = meanAge:sdAge, names_vary = "slowest")


# A tibble: 4 × 11
  name     meanAge_N sdAge_N meanAge_NA sdAge_NA meanAge_Y sdAge_Y meanAge_F sdAge_F meanAge_M sdAge_M
  <chr>        <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 Diabetes      21      3.61       36.8    20.5       31      8.12      NA      NA        NA      NA  
2 HIV           28.6   14.3        38.3    19.4       26.8    7.14      NA      NA        NA      NA  
3 Sex           NA     NA          NA      NA         NA     NA         30.8    14.4      30.1    13.8
4 Smoke         35.5   16.4        24       5.57      30.2   14.9       NA      NA        NA      NA
```

Comment: Very helpful and gives me what I need, thank you. Follow up question - when using pivot_longer() is it possible to preserve the order of the columns or is alphabetical the only option?

Comment: The `names_vary` parameter gives a couple options but I think it's relatively new and might be fleshed out more in upcoming versions. I think you could change the output order if you re-sort in the prior step and/or make your names into ordered factors.